# Row is not deleted in PHPMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, wamp

I have a problem deleting a row in PHPMyAdmin. When I click the 'Delete' button to delete the row, at the top it says

```
Showing rows 0 - 0 ( ~1 total , Query took 0.0004 sec)

SELECT * 
FROM  "counters_total"
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

But the row is still there, even after refreshing. The only way to delete the row is to click 'Edit' -> GO, and then when I delete it it is deleted.  I am using Entity Framework, maybe the table / row is locked - but if so, shouldn't I get an error?

Using WAMP: Apache/2.4.2 (Win64) PHP/5.4.3 on Windows 7.

Comment: I've run into the same problem lately in PHPMyAdmin 2.11.8.1. It seems to work when I log out and back in again.